# Weird Slice Pattern In Debug Mode - Go and Visual Studio Code

Tags: go, debugging, visual-studio-code, slice

So it's not a huge deal because I end up with the result I want but I'm wondering if anyone knows why my slice goes through a back and forth pattern when I'm working with the debugger in visual studio code.

Here is what I have:

```
                partialKey := code + id + service
                state:="CA"
                clientId := "test"

                var combo = []string{partialKey + clientId + state,
                    partialKey + clientId + util.Constants.DEFAULT_STATE
                    partialKey + util.Constants.DEFAULT_ID + state,
                    partialKey + util.Constants.DEFAULT_ID + util.Constants.DEFAULT_STATE,
                }
```

When I debug the code and click the step over button it does this weird pattern starting with the first line of the slice (var combo =... so I'll call that line1 and the last line will be line4).
line1
line2
line1
line2
line3
line2
line3
line4
line3
line4

then after that i get the expected four item slice with the correct format so it's not really an issue but i'm just curious if this is a Go thing Or is this caused by the visual studio code debugger and can someone tell me why one or the other does this?

Comment: I observe it as well, my guess is that it steps between different expressions so that you could step-into some of them if you wish.

Comment: It's possible that this is due to bugs in Go's compiler (emitting a wrong or less-intuitive line infos). An easy way to check what line info was generated is to use dlv from the command line and the `disassemble` command.

Answer (score 1):

This is the behaviour of the delve debugger in this kind of array declaration.

What's happening is that each item in the array needs to be constructed before being inserted into the array. Therefore when stepping over the debugger stops at each expression.

```
var combo = []string{
  partialKey + clientId + state,                                        // EXP 1
  partialKey + clientId + util.Constants.DEFAULT_STATE,                 // EXP 2
  partialKey + util.Constants.DEFAULT_ID + state,                       // EXP 3
  partialKey + util.Constants.DEFAULT_ID + util.Constants.DEFAULT_STATE,// EXP 4
}
```

If we extract the item construction from the array initialisation the array is initialised in one step.

```
item1 := partialKey + clientId + state               
item2 := partialKey + clientId + util.Constants.DEFAULT_STATE
item3 := partialKey + util.Constants.DEFAULT_ID + state        
item4 := partialKey + util.Constants.DEFAULT_ID + util.Constants.DEFAULT_STATE

var combo = []string{item1, item2, item3, item4} // This is now one expression
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the debugger goes up one line between each expression in the first case. 
Would appreciate anyone with that knowledge to please chime in but I suspect it's due to the array initialisation being subtly different in the compiled code.